# Travelling from Athens to Araxos Airport (Patras)

Tags: airport-transfer, greece, athens, gpa

I have a flight from the Araxos Airport at 14:30 on a Monday. What is the best way to reach there from Athens? And how long does it take?

Sources on the internet say that we should take a train from Athens to Kiato, and then a bus to the airport. But I can't find an official website giving the timings of the buses etc.

Where can I find genuine information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Athens to Patras

Best would be to take the coach/bus. If I were you I would pick the morning 8:30 *Express* bus according to the official Patras coach station [website](http://www.ktelachaias.gr/?module=default&pages_id=24&lang=el). I have no personal experience, but various sources say it takes ~ 3 hours (maybe a bit less).

### Patras to Araxos airport

The reason you cannot find any information, is because it doesn't exist :) The aforementioned official website does not list timetables for local routes. But they [do serve](http://www.ktelachaias.gr/?module=site__downloads&view=23&lang=el) the airport. Whenever there is a flight, they offer a bus service to and from the airport. The only unofficial website I could find mentioning is [here](http://www.patrasinfo.eu/en/araxos-airport-patras/to-from.html). It takes ~ 1 hour and costs 4 euros per person, per leg (2012 price, might have gone up). Source for this information was a travel forum (in greek).

Hope that helps!